# Charts are printing grainy artifacts from the viewer, but not on screen or PDF

Tags: printing, ssrs-2008, pie-chart

SSRS 2008 R2

Pie Chart with CustomAttribute PieDrawingStyle = Concave

Everything looks great on screen, PDF looks great, printing PDF is fine, printing from the viewer looks like the printer is running out of ink, or its trying to print it in 8-bit, it just looks bad.

The concave looks awesome and our clients love it, but they do a lot of printing and forcing them to always go to pdf first isn't an option.

Comment: Engineers at Microsoft have reproduced this in certain scenarios, still no fix as of now.

Comment: Microsoft: I just wanted to update you on this again. It is taking some time for the dev team to take a look into this issue. We know that an export to PDF prints correctly and the print preview is correct. So at this point we need to find out if RS is sending something incorrect to the printer or if we are depending on the printer driver(s) to do something and they are doing it incorrectly. I will let you know when I have more information. Sorry again for the delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft developers have decided it is an issue, but its going to be too much work to fix as a cumulative update and it will have to wait until the **next release of SQL Server**, which is supposed to be next year around this time.